# Aligning Text And Images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm having difficulties with a particular section. The desired goal, is for it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUA2S.jpg).

And I'm getting [this](https://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/GvayLW).

```
.timeline {
    text-align: center;
}

#about-us {
    ul {
        &:before {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 50%;
            width: 2px;
            margin-left: -1.5px;
            content: '';
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    }
    img {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border-radius: 50%;

    }
}

.timeline-img {
    border: 7px solid #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.timeline-1,
.timeline-3 {
    .timeline-info {
        float: left;
        width: 45%;
        text-align: right;
    }
}

.timeline-2,
.timeline-4 {
    .timeline-info {
        float: right;
        width: 45%;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

Also, the grey line in the end overflows a little bit, and I can't make it as long as the last image.

Comment: Are you opposed to using Bootstrap's grid system for this? I'm working on a solution using the grid system now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some of the bootstrap class to [reverse flow](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#direction)

> Use `.flex-row` to set a horizontal direction (the browser default), or `.flex-row-reverse` to start the horizontal direction from the opposite side.

- HTML possible update

```
<ul class="timeline">
    <li class="timeline-1 d-flex flex-row-reverse"></li>
    <li class="timeline-2 d-flex"></li>
    <li class="timeline-3 d-flex flex-row-reverse"></li>
    <li class="timeline-4 d-flex"></li>
    <li class="timeline-5 "></li>
</ul>
```

Then, you can add a pseudo to fill an empty space of same width of `timeline-info` :

- CSS possible update

```
.timeline li:before {
  content:'';
  width: 45%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gxJvBj

Comment: Thanks for solution, I just got a few questions:
1.If the `.timeline li:before` has a width of 45% and the .timeline-info has the same width, that means, that there is 10% left, so where does it go? Is it the image div? Because I tried to give the mentioned elements 50% width and the imgs  didn't break to the next line.
2. I've noticed that the images have lost around 8px of width. When I decreased the widths of the mentioned elements in the first question from 45% to 40%, the imgs regained their full width, but were slightly off center. Were the 45% a sweetspot or was it something else?

Comment: @KestVir best would be to set flex:1 to both timeline-info and :before  ( https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gxJvBj updated) and forget about width, browser will deal it at best and they will share evenly space that center image will not use. that is the typical flex thing, it is flexible :)  when you set static values, the browser will try to adapt and elements can expand, shrink or overflow